# Elements outside vuejs transition component applied with transition effect

Tags: css, vue.js, vue-router, css-transforms

Vue Version
2.6.10

Please see the [reproduction](https://jsfiddle.net/simonmysun/4pta0x68/).

```
<router-link to="/a"><a name="/a">[a]</a></router-link>
<router-link to="/b"><a name="/b">[b]</a></router-link>
<router-link to="/c"><a name="/c">[c]</a></router-link>
<transition :name="transitionName">
  <router-view></router-view>
</transition>
```

There are three routes here. Switching from A to B, the router links are moving.

The router links should remain still since they are not in the transition tag. They are animated in my browser.

I have tried my best to minify the reproduction. Using other transition effects, removing the mounted hook or the focus operation, the effect doesn't show up. Switching between other route pairs also does not trigger this effect.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what is happening. Because of `overflow: hidden`, I did not see the change of `clientWidth`. Without the scrollbar I did not see the change of `scrollX` when the `input` element is focused. That's why it looks like the links are animated.